# Vigenere giving wrong result

Tags: c, cs50, vigenere

The task is to give a keyword argument when you run the program, which I saved as a `string k` then the user inputs text and the program will output that inputted text according to the keyword. A = 0, B = 1, so if the keyword is ABABA and the text is hello, it would output hflmo.

If I run the program giving `argv[1]` as "abc" then plaintext `pt` as "hello", I should be getting "hfnlp", but instead I get "hnflv", why doesn't the last letter encipher correctly?

```
    string k = argv[1];
    int l = strlen(argv[1]);
    printf("plaintext: ");
    string pt = get_string("");
    printf("ciphertext: ");
    for (int i = 0, shift = 0; i < strlen(pt); i++)
    {    
        if (!isalpha(pt[i]))
        {
            printf("%c", pt[i]);
        }
        else
        {
            if (isupper(pt[i]))
            {
                if (isupper(k[shift]))
                {
                    printf("%c", (((pt[i] - 65) + (k[shift % l] - 65)) %26) + 65);
                    shift++;
                }
                else
                {
                    printf("%c", (((pt[i] - 65) + (k[shift % l] - 97)) %26) + 65);
                    shift++;
                }
            }
            else if (islower(pt[i]))
            {
                if (isupper(k[shift]))
                {
                    printf("%c", (((pt[i] - 97) + (k[shift % l] - 65)) %26) + 97);
                    shift++;
                }
                else
                {
                    printf("%c", (((pt[i] - 97) + (k[shift % l] - 97)) %26) + 97);
                    shift++;
                }
            }
        }    
    }                               
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "[How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)"

Comment: Can you briefly explain what the task is?

Comment: I have added the explanation, sorry, I thought because this problem has been posted with different problems a lot, that most would know what it was.

Comment: Please upgrade the shown code to a [mre]. Consider providing the data to process in hard-coded initialised arrays. Otherwise make sure that the input is provided in a non-ambiguous way, too.

Comment: Don't use magic numbers. Use `'A'` instead of `'65'` etc.

Comment: Can I ask why? @Jabberwocky

Comment: @Remitto yes, because it's more readable, it expresses your intention, you don't need to look at an ASCII table or know it by heart and it's portable (your system might have another encoding than ASCII though this is unlikely).

Comment: @Jabberwocky, ah okay, understood. To be honest, a lot of this assignment's focus was on the ASCII table so I wanted to show I understood it in my code. But I guess the letter will be a better choice in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lines

```
if (isupper(k[shift]))
```

are missing the modulo calculation. The correct version is:

```
if (isupper(k[shift % l]))
```

It might be clearer if you put this calculation at some central place in the `for`-loop:

```
shift %= l;
```